# JQuery Comments section not using correct username and not storing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I'm using Jquery-comments by Viima. I am facing two issues while trying to use this plugin.

1. It is not storing data, the data is stored in a data.json file and that information is stored only temporarily. When i refresh the page, my comment goes away.
2. I cannot get it to use my Username that I have in AngularJS

Things i've tried:

I tried putting the angular data directly into the JSON, in the included JS file, and in the HTML. I consistently received undefined.

Here's how I initialize the library in **HTML**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#comments-container').comments({
                profilePictureURL: 'https://viima-app.s3.amazonaws.com/media/user_profiles/user-icon.png',
                roundProfilePictures: true,
                textareaRows: 1,
                enableAttachments: true,
                getComments: function(success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(commentsArray);
                    }, 500);
                },
                postComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(data);
                    }, 500);
                },
                putComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(data);
                    }, 500);
                },
                deleteComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success();
                    }, 500);
                },
                upvoteComment: function(data, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(data);
                    }, 500);
                },
                uploadAttachments: function(dataArray, success, error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        success(dataArray);
                    }, 500);
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the **data.json** file that contains a sample comment:

```
var commentsArray = [  
{  
"id": 1,
"parent": null,
"created": "2015-01-01",
"modified": "2015-01-01",
"content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed  posuere interdum sem. Quisque ligula eros ullamcorper quis, lacinia quis  facilisis sed sapien. Mauris varius diam vitae arcu.",
"fullname": "{{ navvm.currentUser.name }}",
"profile_picture_url":   "https://app.viima.com/static/media/user_profiles/user-icon.png",
"created_by_admin": false,
"created_by_current_user": false,
"upvote_count": 3,
"user_has_upvoted": false
}
]
```

Here is the name section from **comment-data.js**:

```
            // Name
        var nameText = commentModel.createdByCurrentUser ? this.options.textFormatter(this.options.youText) : commentModel.fullname;
        var name = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'name'
        });
        if(commentModel.profileURL) {
            var link = $('<a/>', {
                href: commentModel.profileURL,
                text: nameText
            });
            name.html(link);
        } else {
            name.text(nameText);
        }
```

This is my sample **angular controller**:

```
(function() {

  angular
.module('meanApp')
.controller('profileCtrl', profileCtrl);

  profileCtrl.$inject = ['$location', 'meanData'];
  function profileCtrl($location, meanData) {
var vm = this;

vm.user = {};

meanData.getProfile()
  .success(function(data) {
    vm.user = data;
  })
  .error(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  }

 })();
```

Comment: Angular + jQuery plugin = oil + water

Comment: So it can't be done? lol

Comment: Is there a way to maybe push the angular data as a string into the JQuery element?

Comment: I don't know if it can be done or not. I just know that using that you're in for a bunch of grief in trying to get the 2 to work together.  I'd search for an alternative plugin that is pure angular. If I couldn't find one I would likely spin up my own directive. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I haven't found an Angular Comment section that includes attachments. I don't believe i could create my own directive that could.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can slog through this with you ... even against my better judgment ;)  Couple of questions 1) What is comment-data.js?  2) You are injecting meanData, which I assume is an angular service, into your controller.  Can you update your question to include the code for that service?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/ Here is what I used for MEANDATA. He explains it way better than I can. Comment data.js is the JSON data the JQuery comments read from. Which ultimately might change.. because the JSON data isn't storing

Comment: There's too many missing pieces to this puzzle for me to effectively help you.  Here's a plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/0NcKBAkSrI6D9lA3NhSt?p=preview) that's the best I could assemble with what you've provided.  If you fork it and add your HTML and jQuery component, then I can look at it and help you further.